# Eclipse Mars hidden windows in Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-mars

I'm having one issue on Mac OS X El Capitan with Eclipse Mars and menu windows. When a menu window opens a new window, it shows in the back of the first one, and moves along with it (if I move the first one, the second one moves with it, but not the other way around). So there are two possible scenarios. If the second window shows a bit (like in [this](http://postimg.org/image/lqgmld435/) image), you still can move it and then interact with it, but if the second window is totally hidden (like [this one](http://postimg.org/image/s9ixmm0kt/) when clicking 'Advanced'), then there's nothing you can do, since it seems impossible to put it on top. Is this a known bug or is there a solution for it?

Comment: PS Please follow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post for how to put images in a post. In particular SO has a pro account with imgur so that images never disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse bug [478975](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478975) is open for this problem.

The problem only occurs when Eclipse (or any Eclipse RCP) is in full-screen mode. It works normally when not full-screen.

Update: A fix for this bug is included in Eclipse Neon (4.6) Release Candidate 3.